# Android R.java doesn't regenerate in Eclipse after SDK & ADT update

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin, adt

I have recently downloaded both the 2.3 and 3.0 SDK for Android using Eclipse.

I have also updated the ADT plug-in to 10.0.0.

However since doing this the R.java file in my project will not regenerate at all, I have tried every solution on the web that google can give me and none of them work.

So I imported my project to a different machine that only has the 2.2 SDK and an older ADT plugin installed and the R.java file regenerates fine on that machine.

Currently on my work machine I am trying to add a png to drawables but the R.java doesn't seem to pick it up meaning I cant use it in my project.

Is there something stupid that I'm missing that I should have done when I upgraded the SDK and ADT?

EDIT: R.java simply wont rebuild at all, even if I change my XML.

The issue is definitely with the 2.3 SDK or ADT 10, it works fine if I have 2.2 and ADT 9

Comment: i think this some time happens due to incorrect format. .png file might not be pure png file, it might have been renamed to .png format or your image name might be containing some capital letters. but these are just  guesses.....

Comment: Saved using an editor "As png" so shouldn't be the cause, it also compiles fine on a different machine with the exact same code and resources, just lower SDK and older ADT installed.

Comment: Moving from Eclispe Ganymede to Eclipse Helios fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a bug within ADT r14 and it isnt really fixed with r15 or r14.  Only thing I can think is to unistall and redownload the older ver 13 and keep using the code from there.

Comment: I updated to Indigo and redownloaded all the files completely deleting Eclipse Helios, it fixed my problem and runs smoother than before.

Answer (score 2):

I recently had this problem as well.  In my case I had type-o in one of my resource xml config files.  This error caused the resource builder to terminate and my R.java was never built.  I tried to delete it first to trigger a rebuild but that did not work.

I temporarily removed the resource file causing the error and then did Project -> Clean and the R.java was correctly built again.

Not sure if will help, but it might get you going in the right direction.

Answer (score -2):

try to clean and Build workspace from eclipse=>project->clean.

me done this it work for me..

Comment: Tried about 400 times now, no effect